# What's the difference between Solve[lhs == rhs, x] and Roots[lhs == rhs, x] in Mathematica 7?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Why does the Roots function exist when you can do the same thing with Solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Roots` only applies to [polynomial equations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Roots.html) such as `x^2==1`.
`Solve` handles polynomial equations over the complex numbers as well, but it lacks a lot of options for more advanced polynomial gymnastics.
For instance `Roots` allows you to specify that you want solutions over the [ring of integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) modulo some `n`, or that you want solutions to quartic solution handled in a special way etc.

In short, if you don't need any of the specail features of `Roots` just stick with `Solve`.

Comment: Also note that Solve output are rules, while Roots output are equations.You can use "ToRules" to convert from equations to rules

Answer (score 2):

When you're actually looking for a root, `Roots` produces a cleaner output.

Also, from the manual:

> `Roots` is generated when `Solve` and
>   related functions cannot produce
>   explicit solutions. Options are often
>   given in such cases.

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Roots.html

Comment: So the only difference is the style of the output?

Comment: Well, and this is how I understand it so don't take it for granted, 'Roots' is one of many algorithms used to solve equations and 'Solve' returns it when it can't give anything better. It's some kind of sub-function.